# jquery script doesnt work after .load()

Tags: jquery

Im just started yesterday with jquery/ajax. And im trying some things out, but I run into a wall.

I have an index file where I include my js script in this script I have two functions (see below)

In the index file I used include to include a php file that contains a table with some rows (rows from mysql). This included file I also use for the .load in my js script (mod/hoofdmenu.php).

One script is for changing the order of the rows by drag and drop, this works perfect.
Other script is for changing 1 row when you click a image (publish/unpublish). This script works also perfect. BUT when I run this script the first script (drag and drop) doenst work anymore. The 'publish/unpublish' script still works.

I think its because the $('#showdata').load('mod/hoofdmenu.php');
All advise/help is very much appreciated.

the includes js file:

```
$(function() {
    $(".entry").live("click",function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var id = $(this).attr("id");
    var dataString = 'id='+ id ;
    var parent = $(this).parent();
    $.ajax({
            url: "save.php",    
            type: "POST",       
            data: dataString,       
            cache: false,
            success: function (html) {  
                $('#showdata').load('mod/hoofdmenu.php');           
            }       
        });
    });
});
$(function() {
    $(".tbl_repeat tbody").tableDnD({
        onDrop: function(table, row) {
            var orders = $.tableDnD.serialize();
            $.post('mod/order.php', { orders : orders });
        }
    });

});
```

Comment: why do you have 2 `$(function() {` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The drag and drop event applied to a DOM element that has now been replaced with the new stuff loaded by the AJAX request.  You need to put the tableDnD behaviour on to the new elements.

There may be some fancy livequery style way of doing this but this should work:

```
function initDnD(root) { 
    root.find(".tbl_repeat tbody").tableDnD({
        onDrop: function(table, row) {
            var orders = $.tableDnD.serialize();
            $.post('mod/order.php', { orders : orders });
        }
    });
};

$(function() {
    $(".entry").live("click",function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var id = $(this).attr("id");
        var dataString = 'id='+ id ;
        var parent = $(this).parent();
        $.ajax({
            url: "save.php",    
            type: "POST",       
            data: dataString,       
            cache: false,
            success: function (html) {  
                $('#showdata').load('mod/hoofdmenu.php', function() {
                    initDnD($('#showdata'));
                });           
            }       
        });
    });
    initDnD($("body"));
});
```

Comment: Thank Gaz for your quick reply.

I tried out your code, I just got one syntax error (one last line, });)

Comment: Gaz,
I'm found the syntax error and the script (drag and drop) works now after I call the 2nd script (the publish/unpublish). But when I refresh the index the drag and drop doenst work only when I click the publish/unpublish first.

Comment: Sorry about the syntax error I've fixed it now.  I also call initDnD on the body during the page load, which should fix your new problem.

Comment: Solved it, I added initDnD($('#showdata')); to a $(document).ready(function() thank you very much Gaz!!

Comment: ah yes, your option is much better then adding an extra ready(function(), tnx! Tried it and it works great!